# AJAX - Cannot receive Servlet response

Tags: ajax

I am trying AJAX for the first time for my school project. I have problem in receiving response from server (response 'status' 0). I've browse through similar problems in the suggested list and try already but the problem still persists. Hope someone can point out what I do wrong with my AJAX code.

Here's my jsp code:

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.IOException"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@ page import="com.p6qgen.*"%>

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Generate Question</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 

    // Checking whether the browser support AJAX or not
    function ajaxFunction() {
        var ajaxReq;  // The variable to hold XMLHttpRequest object
        //alert("ajaxFunction()");
        try {
            // Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari
            ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try{
                ajaxReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        //alert("Ajax object created...");
        /*
         * Start of server response handling
         */
        ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = parseXml;

        // Parsing the xml document
        function parseXml() {
            if(ajaxReq.readyState == 4){
                alert("in parseXml");
                if(ajaxReq.status == 200) {
                    alert("Status OK!");
                    var numQs = ajaxReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("numqs")[0];
                    alert(numQs);
                    for(var i=0; i<numQs; i++) {
                        num = i+1;
                        var question = ajaxReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("question")[i];
                        setQuestion(num, question.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    }
                } else if(ajaxReq.status == 404) {
                    alert("Page Not Found");
                } else {
                    alert("Error: " + ajaxReq.status)
                }
            }
            /* Just for debugging
            else {
                switch(ajaxReq.readyState) {
                case 0: alert("Not Initialize"); break;
                case 1: alert("Connection Establish"); break;
                case 2: alert("Request received"); break;
                case 3: alert("Answer in Progress"); break;
                }
            } */
        }

        /*function setQuestion(num, question) {
             var qsTag = document.getElementById("question");

             var qBody = "<font size=\"4\"> Question " + num;
             qBody += "<p>" + question +"</p></font>";
             // if the messageBody element has been created simple replace it otherwise
             // append the new element
             if (qsTag.childNodes[0]) {
                 qsTag.replaceChild(qBody,  qsTag.childNodes[0]);
             } else {
                 qsTag.appendChild(qBody);
             }
        }*/
        /*
         * End of server response handling
         */

        // Extract selected values from dropdown lists and store in corresponding var
        alert("going to show...");
        var numT01 = document.getElementById('numT01').value;
        var numT02 = document.getElementById('numT02').value;
        var numT03 = document.getElementById('numT03').value;
        var numT04 = document.getElementById('numT04').value;
        var numT05 = document.getElementById('numT05').value;
        var numT06 = document.getElementById('numT06').value;
        var numT07 = document.getElementById('numT07').value;
        var numT08 = document.getElementById('numT08').value;
        // Prepare query string
        var queryStr = "?num1=" + numT01 + "&num2=" + numT02 + "&num3=" + numT03 +
                        "&num4=" + numT04 + "&num5=" + numT05 + "&num6=" + numT06 +
                        "&num7=" + numT07 + "&num8=" + numT08;
        alert("dbg#" + numT01);
        // Send request to server (server-side 'QGenerator')
        ajaxReq.open("GET", "QGenerator" + queryStr, true);
        //ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryStr.length);
        //ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        ajaxReq.send(null);
    }




    //-->
    </script>



    <h1 align="center">Percentage Question</h1>
    <br>
    <form name="qtype">
        <table width="800" cellspacing="5" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt1.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ1">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT01">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt2.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ2">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT02">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt3.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ3">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT03">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt4.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ4">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT04">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt5.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ5">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT05">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt6.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ6">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT06">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt7.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ7">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT07">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="200" align="right" valign="middle">
                    <input type="image" src="Pix/qt8.jpg" width="96" height="30" name="typ8">
                </td >
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numT08">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <font size="4">
                        No of Questions to generate per page:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="numQs_page">
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                        </select>
                    </font>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle">
                        <button onclick="ajaxFunction()">
                            <img src="Pix/genQs.jpg" width= "252" height="50" />
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="question"></div>
</body>
```

And here's my servlet code:

```
    package com.p6qgen;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    //import org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log;

    /**
    * Servlet implementation class QGenerator
    */
    @WebServlet("/QGenerator")
    public class QGenerator extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

DBAccess dbAccess;
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

//int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, total_qs;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public QGenerator() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    try {
        dbAccess = new DBAccess();
        conn = dbAccess.getConnection(); 
        stmt = conn.createStatement();            

        dbAccess.clearTable(conn, "T_Temp");
        dbAccess.clearTable(conn, "T_Question");
        //int num1 = 5;
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
        int num3 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num3"));
        int num4 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num4"));
        int num5 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num5"));
        int num6 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num6"));
        int num7 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num7"));
        int num8 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num8"));
        int total_qs = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8;
        System.out.println(total_qs);
        System.out.println("num1: " + num1);
        int tbl_cnt = 0; // to count the solution tables created
        // Generating the question
        do {
            if(num1!=0) {
                T_Q01 q01 = new T_Q01();
                q01.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q01.generateSol();
                num1--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num2!=0) {
                T_Q02 q02 = new T_Q02();
                q02.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q02.generateSol();
                num2--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num3!=0) {
                T_Q03 q03 = new T_Q03();
                q03.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q03.generateSol();
                num3--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num4!=0) {
                T_Q04 q04 = new T_Q04();
                q04.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q04.generateSol();
                num4--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num5!=0) {
                T_Q05 q05 = new T_Q05();
                q05.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q05.generateSol();
                num5--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num6!=0) {
                T_Q06 q06 = new T_Q06();
                q06.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q06.generateSol();
                num6--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num7!=0) {
                T_Q07 q07 = new T_Q07();
                q07.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q07.generateSol();
                num7--;
                total_qs--;
            }
            if(num8!=0) {
                T_Q08 q08 = new T_Q08();
                q08.generateQuestion();
                tbl_cnt++;
                String tbl_name = "T_S" + tbl_cnt;
                dbAccess.dropTable(conn, tbl_name); // delete table if existed
                dbAccess.createTable(conn, tbl_name); // created a new table
                q08.generateSol();
                num8--;
                total_qs--;
            }
        } while (total_qs > 0);

        // Counting total number of questions in T_Question table
        int row = dbAccess.countRow(conn, "Q_ID", "T_Question");

        response.getOutputStream().println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        response.getOutputStream().println("<qpage>");
        response.getOutputStream().println("<numqs>");
        response.getOutputStream().println(row);
        response.getOutputStream().println("</numqs>");
        for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
            int q_id = i+1;
            response.getOutputStream().println("<number>");
            response.getOutputStream().println(q_id + ".");
            response.getOutputStream().println("</number>");
            response.getOutputStream().println("<question>");
            String q_val = dbAccess.selectValue(conn, "Q_Val", "T_Question", "Q_ID", q_id);
            response.getOutputStream().println(q_val);
            response.getOutputStream().println("</question>");
        }
        response.getOutputStream().println("</qpage>");

        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();

        stmt.close();
        conn.close(); 
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("-----SQLException-----");
        System.err.println("doGet Error: " + e.getSQLState());
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {


}

}
```

Sorry for posting very long code, but I think this might give a good info to analyze my problem.

As 'BalusC' suggested in 'Servlet response to AJAX request is empty' post, I've already try to include:

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But this still does not solve the problem.
Kindly please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/xmlhttprequest-and-status-code-0) article fits your problem. You will have to cancel the default behaviour of your "submit" button. The [button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) tag has an attribute `type`, which will be "submit" if it is not defined. So you have two choices:

1. Change your button to `<button type="button" onclick="...">...</button>`
2. Add an `return false;` after `ajaxReq.send(null);`

Also there is an error in your `parseXml`-function. `getElementsByTagName(...)` returns a NodeList including all `numqs`-nodes. Therefor the value of `numQs` will be a xml node, so the condition of your for-loop will fail. You will have to parse the `nodeValue` of numQs before using it in the for-loop.

```
var numQs = parseInt(ajaxReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("numqs")[0].nodeValue, 10);
for (var i = 0; i < numQs; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, man! It's solve the problem, now I can get status reply '200'. Sorry to say that I can't vote-up as I don't have 15reputation. Btw, why do I need to add 'return false'?

Comment: `return false;` will prevent the browser from submitting the form which would be the default behaviour of a submit button.

Comment: Thanks, john_doe, for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out error in 'parseXml' function. I'll correct it. As a noob in web development I always do such kind of mistake :).